# How to prove that the expected squared error associated with the optimal combination weight is smaller than the minimum of 2 forecast variances?

Tags: finance-mathematics, forecasting, econometrics

I am looking at linear combination of two forecasts (Bates and Granger, 1969). I would like to understand how to prove that the expected squared error associated with the optimal combination weight is smaller than the minimum of 2 forecast variances. I have come across it quite a number of times in literature and textbook. However, after giving it much thought, I am still unable to prove it.

Below I have attached the proof. I have successfully managed to prove up to step 7.28. I am just left the last line boxed in blue to understand. Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function under study is a quadratic form that is positive semidefinite.  The critical point is therefore a global minimum.  If the minimum does not lie between 0 and 1, then simply choose the smaller of the two variances.

Comment: Hi: I think what user`8764 is saying is that you can take the derivative of the function, solve for the minimum ( k*) and be sure that it's not a local minimum because the second derivative of the function is positive and he function is quadratic ( the two imply that function is convex ).

Comment: and, I left out his main point which is that, if k* doesn't lie between zero and one when solved for, then find the values at k = 0 and k = 1 and take the minimum.

Comment: It's implied that he knows how to minimize the function given that he's derived up to the inequality. He just needs to remember that a quadratic funcrion has a single optima, which is the crux of his question.

Comment: no problem. I was just trying to clarify. your answer was great.

Comment: @user18764 you have been of great help! I really appreciate it (:

Comment: No problem!  I initially tried to play with the inequality explicitly before realizing there was a simpler argument.